# Angular Canvas Whiteboard

Tags: angular

I recently started using Angular and wanted to do a first project enabling the user to draw stuff on a canvas. I used this package for that https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-canvas-whiteboard and followed the README instructions.

Now the problem is that the canvas does not show up, I only get a thin line up top. I recreated the issue in stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axqys4

Can someone point out why this happens? 
Down below is a paragraph talking about current limitations:
If there are problems with the sizing of the parent container, the canvas size will not be the wanted size. It may sometimes be width: 0, height: 0. If this is the case you may want to call a resize event for the window for the size to be recalculated.

```
if (this.isCanvasOpened) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
      }, 1);
    }
```

If that is the issue, where do I put this stuff?

Comment: Can you try my forked example? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kaj91f?file=src/styles.css There were only small changes in `styles.css`

Comment: @yurzui yes thats it :D. I thought the default size would be bit more sane